# How to merge QuerySets from the same model

Tags: django, merge, django-queryset

I want to combine (|) a series of QuerySets:**all_english_text** in a loop:

```
    tag_result = Tag.objects.get(id=all_tag[index])

    all_english_text = tag_result.notes.all().values('english_text', 'id')
```

by the following def:

```
def list_by_tag_post(request):

# get POST
all_tag = request.POST.getlist('tag_list')

for index in range(len(all_tag)):
    tag_result = Tag.objects.get(id=all_tag[index])

    all_english_text = tag_result.notes.all().values('english_text', 'id')
    result = list(chain(*all_english_text)) # Merging method

all_english_text = result

# to template
context = {'all_english_text': all_english_text, 'all_tag': all_tag}
return render(request, 'list_by_tag.html', context)
```

3 methods were tried, they all didn't work:

```
result = list(chain(*all_english_text)) # Merging method 1
result = chain(*all_english_text) # Merging method 2
result = all_english_text.union(*all_english_text))# Merging method 3
```

Comment: Can you add the `Tag` and `Note` models to your question?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible in a single query.

Without knowing what `Tag.notes` is it may not be exactly right. I'm assuming it's a reverse relationship from a `ForeignKey` on a `Note` model (`Note.tag`)

```
all_english_text = Note.objects.filter(tag_id__in=all_tag).values('english_text', 'id')
```